# Tags concerning variables and bindings

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Should the tags [bound-variables](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bound-variables) [binders](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binders) (and possibly [de-bruijn-indexing](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/de-bruijn-indexing)) be merged? There probably won't be any question exclusively discussing binders and *not* bound variables. De bruijn indices, in my opinion, should also be merged, but it's slightly different so it depends on consensus.

Comment: I would say look at the tag info but you are changing the tag info.  From a person using proof assistants they my seem the same. For someone implementing a system in code they could have very different meanings.

Comment: binders and bound-variables are synonyms, de-bruijn-indexing is a specific implementation technique